# PyTorch - Cuda error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: cuda, pytorch

I have a problem about CUDA and PyTorch. I am trying to run a simple code from [SinGAN implementation](https://github.com/tamarott/SinGAN) but I got a Runtime Cuda error. Here is information about Cuda and PyTorch.

- PyTorch: 1.3.1
- Cuda: 10.0
- Torchvision: 0.4.2

I installed all of them with conda. Here is the simple code that I tried:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from skimage import io as img
import numpy as np

x = img.imread('...')
x = x[:,:,:,None]
x = x.transpose((3,2,0,1))/255
x = torch.from_numpy(x)

print(torch.cuda.is_available())

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    x = x.cuda()
    #x = x.to(torch.device('cuda'))

    x = x.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
```

Output:

> True
>
> RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

As a result, although `cuda.is_available()` returns True, there is a CUDA RuntimeError. And I did not handle this problem.

Comment: What's your card? Can you check its Cuda capability? It looks like it's not supported anymore.

Comment: That error means that Pytorch has been built without support for your card

Comment: I am using Tesla K20m and according to the documentation that my company provides about the server, supported Cuda version for this card is 10.1.

Comment: It isn't supported by Torch binary builds. Torch eliminated compute capability 3.x and 5.x devices some time ago

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, thank you so much for the information. According to [1], all Tesla K series GPUs have 2.x and 3.x compute capability. This means all these GPUs cannot be used with PyTorch? 
[1] https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: You can use compute 3.0/3.5 devices with  PyTorch, but you will have to build the code yourself with support for those cards enabled. The standard binary distribution does not have that support enabled